# Do subdirectories of a domain have their own kind of internal ranking to the point that it matters in which one we publish new content?

Tags: seo, blog, subdirectory, technical-seo

Let's say I have a blog on `example.com/blog/` and now I decide to create another blog inside `example.com/product/blog/`

If `example.com/blog/` has been out there for 7 years and its content has been indexed for much longer, would it be better for SEO to keep posting blog posts on it instead of moving some away to some other subdirectory?

Do subdirectories of a domain have their own kind of "internal ranking" to the point that it matters which subdirectory we use to publish our content?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should worry provided the blog posts on both the folders are meaningfully and sufficiently interlinked. For example, if you are going to post a new blog in /product/blog that is related to an old post in /blog, you may choose to link the new blog from some section like "related content" of the old one. But the links should be meaningful and not just for the sake of internal links.

Regarding SEO, a good practice is to maintain a good link architecture irrespective of the folders/platforms.